# How to change the casing of mat-calendar-period-button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have changed the format of the text of this button. The problem I am facing that it automatically changes the text to the upper case. I want to make it title case (just first letter is capital the rest of the letters are lower cases). Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You could try `text-transform: lowercase;`. See the documentation for the [`text-transform` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) for more info.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It can be changed to only lowercase. I want to make it title cased. title case only affects the first letter only. For example: According to css text-transform, title case of "dec" is "Dec". Also, the title case of "DEC" is "DEC". not "Dec". I am having trouble there.

Comment: I think it should be `text-transform: capitalize;` as Samiul wants the first letter uppercase only, otherwise all the text would be lowercase.

Comment: capitalize doesn't make other letters in lower case. they remain as they were. The first letter transforms into upper case only. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a bit of css there:

```
.mat-calendar-period-button {
  text-transform: lowercase;

  &::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes from `MatCalendarHeader`. Looking at the template the month and the year comes from [periodButtonText](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/c1d898661b6055c67090f0cb8b7727b6335733b8/src/material/datepicker/calendar-header.html#L6). Looking further in the code `perioduttonText` is a getter and at the end they called [toLocaleUpperCase](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/c1d898661b6055c67090f0cb8b7727b6335733b8/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L71). So there is no build in way to change this.

What you can do is change the calendar header with your template like is shown in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/drlavqmevyo).

Comment: On the pop up it shows nothing. Can you check again, please?